# Multiple keys in same keyring

Tags: bouncycastle, pgp

This might be a very basic question and might have been discussed, but I want to make sure I understand it right and hence stating along with problem

1. My company is to get files from 5 different vendors. Each of them will encrypt file before sending to me. They have also sent their public keys to me in advance - so I have 5 public keys from individual 5 vendors
2. Now my question is can I make a single keyring composed of those 5 public keys?
3. If the answer to 2 is yes, then in my program can I use keyrong to decrypt message from any of those vendors with KeyRing?

I am trying to use bouncycastle for my operation if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the bouncycastle API does not provide this functionality out of the box.

You will need some extra coding to achieve it through the bouncy castle class PGPPublicKeyRingCollection.

You can also check this example from a commercial BC wrapper that provides such feature:
http://www.didisoft.com/java-openpgp/examples/import-keys/